# How to make a variable random multiple times with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I am trying to make a card memory game in jQuery but I have a small problem. I want it so when you click on a card the image is random every time you start the program. I am also trying to make it so the image that one card has is then shared with another random card. Right now I have the cards but when an image is randomly chosen, its applied to all cards. Here is my JavaScript so far. If anyone could help me out here that would be great.

```
var score = 0;
var images = ["images are here"];
Image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
$("#score").text("Number of turns: " + score);

$(".cards").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).animate({
       height: "+=10px",
        width: "+=10px"
    });
});
$(".cards").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "-=10px",
        width: "-=10px"
    });
});

$(".cards").click(function () {
    score++;
    $("#score").text("Number of turns: " + score);

    $(this).css({
        "background-image": 'url(' + Image + ')'
    });
});
```

Edit: Here is the html:

```
<body>
     <h5>card game</h5>

    <div id="card1" class="cards"></div>
    <div id="card2" class="cards"></div>
    <div id="card3" class="cards"></div>
    <div id="card4" class="cards"></div>
    <div id="card5" class="cards"></div>
    <div id="card6" class="cards"></div>
    <div id="score"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stared at this for a good long time before figuring it out.  Here's your problem:
Image is only set ONE time.  You need to re-assign `Image` every time the user clicks.
Here is how your code should look:

```
var score = 0;
var images = ["images are here"];
$("#score").text("Number of turns: " + score);

$(".cards").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).animate({
       height: "+=10px",
        width: "+=10px"
    });
});
$(".cards").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "-=10px",
        width: "-=10px"
    });
});

$(".cards").click(function () {
    score++;
    $("#score").text("Number of turns: " + score);

    Image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    $(this).css({
        "background-image": 'url(' + Image + ')'
    });
});
```

Note: The method you are using for randomization doesn't guarantee that the same card won't pop up twice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, you don't want to choose the card randomly at the time the card is clicked, otherwise you can't guarantee that each card will only show up twice, let alone changing while the game is played. Instead, you want to shuffle the deck once at the very beginning. Here's one way to code the shuffle:

```
var N = 10; // number of images
var indices = new Array(2*N);
for( var i=0 ; i<2*N ; ++i ) indices[i] = i>>1; // 0,0,1,1,2,2,...
// Do a Fisher-Yates shuffle
for( var i=2*N-1 ; 1<=i ; --i )
{
  var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * (i+1) ); // random 0 <= j <= i
  if( i == j ) continue;
  // Swap i and j
  indices[i] ^= indices[j];
  indices[j] ^= indices[i];
  indices[i] ^= indices[j];
}
```

Change N to be the number of distinct images. Then the number of cards in your deck is 2*N.

After running the above code, access your shuffled deck as images[indices[0]], images[indices[1]], images[indices[2]], ..., images[indices[2*N-1]]. Each image will show up exactly twice in this sequence in a random order.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Kind of confused on this xD I get what you are saying but im wondering how I would go about shuffling the actual image URLs and then have them chosen to be shown on the cards. Im probably sounding like a noob right now :p

Comment: If you have 10 images, you don't just want the 10 images shuffled - you want 20 images shuffled where each image shows up twice in the deck, right? For this you would use images[indices[i]] where 0<=i<20. Or if you prefer, use shuffled_deck(i) where shuffled_deck is the function shuffled_deck(i) { return images[indices[i]]; }.

Comment: Ah I get it. Where should I put in my code? I tried "background-image": 'url(' + images[indices[i]] + ')' but that only uses one image. If I swap i to j it only uses a different picture. Im assuming im putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: The click handler function where you set the background image needs to have the number i passed in. If you have 10 distinct images, then 0<=i<20; i is the index of the card position, not the image number. One way to do this is with the onClick="return showCard(5)" attribute on the 5th card, onClick="return showCard(6)" on the 6th card, etc. Then the showCard(i) function is where you would show the card images[indices[i]] on div or img with id="card"+i.